# select all and unselect checkbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 checkbox working properly with check all and uncheck all..not workin with when you click on 'select all' and if uncheck anyone of checkbox then 'select All' remain in check status...

code is here....

```
 function selectAll(status) {
       $('input[name=selectedId]').each(function(){
         $(this).prop('checked', status);
      });

    }


   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="1" />1 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="2" />2 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="3" />3 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="4" />4 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="5" />5 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="6" />6 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="6" />6 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="7" />7 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="8" />8 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="9" />9 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="10" />10<br/>
```

Comment: Please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Also compare the `length` of `checkbox` with `length` of `checked` checkboxes

```js
function selectAll() {
  var checked = this.checked;
  $('input[name=selectedId]').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('checked', checked);
  });
}
$('#selectall').on('change', selectAll);
$('input[name=selectedId]').change(function() {
  $('#selectall').prop('checked', $('input[name=selectedId]:checked').length == $('input[name=selectedId]').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" id="selectall" />Select all
<br />
<br />

<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="1" />1
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="2" />2
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="3" />3
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="4" />4
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="5" />5
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="6" />6
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="6" />6
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="7" />7
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="8" />8
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="9" />9
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="10" />10
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

## ?

```js
function selectAll(status) {
       $('input[name="selectedId"]').each(function(){
         $(this).prop('checked', status);
      });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <button onclick="selectAll(true)">Select All</button>
   <button onclick="selectAll(false)">Unselect All</button>
<br>
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="1" />1 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="2" />2 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="3" />3 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="4" />4 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="5" />5 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="6" />6 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="6" />6 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="7" />7 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="8" />8 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="9" />9 <br />
   <input type="checkbox" class="selectedId" name="selectedId" id="10" />10<br/>
```